# What is the solution of $T(n, m) = T(n, m-1) + T(n-1, m) + c$?

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation

Consider the recurrence
$$
T(n,m) = T(n,m-1) + T(n-1,m) + c,
$$
with base cases $T(n,0) = T(0,m) = 1$.

This is the complexity of a recursive algorithm for the longest common subsequence, I know that the complexity is exponential and equals $\Theta(2^i)$, but I'm not sure if $i=\max(n, m)$ or $i=nm$. Also, how can I demonstrate it using induction?

Comment: I assume you're trying to _solve_ that recurrence, as opposed to determining the "complexity" of computing it?

Comment: Hint: Draw the recursion tree for small n, m. Do you see a pattern?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solving or approximating recurrence relations for sequences of numbers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers)

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I couldn't find a simplified formula using the recursion tree, now I'm not even sure if the function is equal to  2^max(n, m).

Comment: Can we assume that $T(n,0)=T(0,m)=1$? Those values should have been given. Otherwise, for example, let $T(n,0)=2^{2^n}$, we may have double exponential growth.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, surprisingly, no answer in that reference question/answers deals with two variables. So it seems not very reasonable to consider this question as a duplicate by our norm.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I forgot to mention that  T(n,0)=T(0,m)=1, and as you said there is no method that could help me solve this recurrence in that reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $f(n,m) = \binom{n+m}{n}$ satisfies the recurrence
$$
f(n,m) = f(n-1,m) + f(n,m-1),
$$
with base cases $f(n,0) = f(0,m) = 1$. This already gives you the solution when $c = 0$, assuming that the base cases are $f(n,0) = f(0,m) = 1$.

One function which satisfies the recurrence, though (in general) not the base case, is $g(n,m) = -c$:
$$ g(n,m) = g(n,m-1) + g(n-1,m) + c. $$
This gives the solution when $c = -1$.

Finally, note that any function of the form $\alpha f(n,m) + g(n,m)$ is also a solution of the recurrence. Since
$$
\alpha f(n,0) + g(n,0) = \alpha f(0,m) + g(0,m) = \alpha - c,
$$
we see that
$$
T(n,m) = (c + 1) f(n,m) + g(n,m) = (c+1) \binom{n+m}{n} - c.
$$